# Determining the logical function of the circuit with diodes

Tags: diodes, logic-gates

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHqgol.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Entry voltages, \$Vin_1\$ and \$Vin_2\$ can be either **5V**, for logical 1, or **0V**, logical 0. \$V_{cc}=5v.\$

Find \$R1\$,\$R2\$ so that \$Vout\$ is, at least, **4V** in the state of 1 and **1V**, at most, in the state of 0.

So explanation that I got, but didn't understood, is that if one of the entry voltages is 5V, then node **a** will be at 4,3V and that other diode will not conduct. (How so?) And after that we can see that there must be a current through D3. It's supposed to be an **OR** function.

Comment: *if one of the entry voltages is 5V, then node a will be at 4,3V and that other diode will not conduct.* When will a diode conduct ? When the voltage on the anode is higher than the voltage on the kathode. Assume Vin1 = 5 V and Vin2 = 0 V, which diode will conduct D1 or D2 ? The one that conducts lifts the voltage at a to 4.3 V. So the other diode will see a higher voltage on it's kathode, so it will not conduct.

Comment: Where is the BJT?

Comment: @Tyler My mistake, only diodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If \$V_{IN}1\$ OR \$V_{IN}2\$ is at 5V, then point \$a\$ will be at 5V - \$V_{diode}\$.

As a diode forward voltage is approximately 0.7V, then point a will indeed be at 4.3V

D3 can only conduct if the cathode is 0.7V below its anode; as such, the only condition that satisfies this (assuming \$V_{CC}\$ to be 5V) is if both D1 and D2 are not conducting; i.e. they are both low. (This is a simplification - there could intermediate voltages involved at the inputs, but I am ignoring them for now).

So you have a Boolean expression that the output will be low if both inputs are also low; using [DeMorgan's theorem](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/demorgan.html), this is the same as:

The output will be high if \$V_1\$ OR \$V_2\$ is high; therefore it is logically an OR gate.